# Una formula que me de las combinaciones sin repetir de 3 digitos: 1 2 3

Tags: matlab

Una formula que me de las combinaciones sin repetir de 3 digitos: 1 2 3
Ejemplo: 
123
213 
312 
231 
321 
132 
231

Comment: Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la función `perms`:

```
>> perms([1 2 3])

ans =

     3     2     1
     3     1     2
     2     3     1
     2     1     3
     1     2     3
     1     3     2
```

Comment: Hermano, me ayudaste muchas gracias!!!